# Menus are not fall bellow the "Ristorante Con Fusion" in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, frontend, responsive

My code snippet is given bellow and im getting the output for mobile view as shown in figure bellow where Menus are not fall bellow the "Ristorante Con Fusion" also if i apply togller button it will shown the button but when i click that button it will not showing any options [not reacting]. Kindly help with this regard .

[THis is my output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/319ve.png)

```html
  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-sm bg-primary fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
           <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Ristorante Con Fusion</a>
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="./aboutus.html">About</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Menu</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>            
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: You need to show your CSS as well

Comment: I had similar issue of drop menus not working a few weeks ago and finally solved by making sure the proper bootstrap css AND JS files AND dependencies were included and included in correct order (that is for example put popper.js before bootstrap.js and so on...)